# Proof about sequences in metric spaces, Hilbert's cube

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

I am having trouble convincing myself that the following proof is correct. The question is from the exercies in a real analysis book and the section is on sequences in metric spaces.

**Background:**

Let $(H^\infty,d)$ be a metric space such that $H^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}^\infty$ and if $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in H^\infty$, then $|a_n| \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In other words, $H^\infty$ is "Hilbert's cube." The metric $d$ in this case is defined by $d(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n-b_n|}{2^n}$.

**Problem:**

Prove that if $\{a^k\}_{k=0}^\infty$ is a sequence of points in $H^\infty$ which converges to $a=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in H^\infty$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_j^k = a_j$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Proof:**

Let $j\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\lim_{k \to \infty} \{a^k\}=a,$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq N$ implies that $$d(a^k,a) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a^k_n-a_n|}{2^n} < \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}.$$

We also have $$\frac{|a^k_j-a_j|}{2^j} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a^k_n-a_n|}{2^n} < \frac{\epsilon}{2^j},$$

which implies that $|a^k_j-a_j| < \epsilon$, so $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_j^k = a_j$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My confusion:**

I don't feel good about the fact that $N$ depends on $j$... but maybe this is OK. How does the proof look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. $N$ does indeed depend on $j$, but it's still a valid proof. You could shorten it however. A proof like the following for example, would be fine:

Fix some $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Observe that 
$$
\lvert a_j^k - a_j \rvert \leq 2^j d(a^k,a)
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. By hypothesis we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} 2^j d(a^k,a) = 0$, so $\lim_{k \to \infty} \lvert a_j^k - a_j \rvert$ must hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the concise proof.

Comment: @EternusVia You're welcome!